# egrep multiple patterns with dashes

Tags: centos, grep

I am trying to match the followings with egrep '201411[08|09|10|11]-[117|111]-'

```
20141108-111-xyz-abc
20141110-117-342-lala
```

But for some reasons, the 2nd character class pattern ([117|111]) doesn't work.  It matches all regardless.

Any idea what goes wrong in my 2nd character class pattern?

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem at hand, but according to `man grep`,`egrep` has been deprecated and `grep -E` should be used.

Comment: thanks for pointing out.  I just tried grep -E just in case.  Same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix up character classes with subpatterns. You need the latter here:

```
grep -E '201411(08|09|10|11)-(117|111)-' file
```

"Character class" means: Every single char from the class (like `[[:alpha:]]`) or selection (`[01][8901]`) may appear.

"Subpattern" (with `|`) means: "One of the patterns separated by `|` may appear."

Comment: Or `grep -E '201411(0[89]|1[01])-11[71]-'`